# Using POLE display (vb.net application)

Tags: vb.net

I want to display info. on pole but no idea at all how to do it.
Please guide.
Thanks

Comment: Can you maybe link to what a "pole display" is?

Comment: Pole display is the display screen that we see at POS, with a pole, just displaying short info to the client

Comment: Well, it's a little old, but Microsoft does seem to have a project to address this sort of thing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429024%28v=winembedded.1002%29.aspx  Does the POS system in question have an API or SDK of any kind?  A little Googling turns up a _lot_ of results in this space.

Answer (score 0):

Many such devices devices use RS232 or RS422 serial communication. Start with the hardware manual for the display to determine how to communicate with it. It will likely detail a specific protocol your application must use to set the message.